# enabling initrd and kernel boot messages grub2

Tags: grub2

In the changelog for grub2 on ubuntu, I noticed that several versions ago it was decided by the maintainers to:
Suppress kernel/initrd progress messages, except in recovery mode

This is counter productive for server installs as it can render a system unbootable and without a method to learn about the possible problem. My question is simple - how does one revert to showing all initrd and kernel boot messages including the processing of init.d scripts before the login prompt? (ie. enable printing of all initrd/kernel progress messages)

I've tried the various "solutions" discussed in answer to similar questions and cannot find a simple, works-everywhere solution. FYI, I'm using grub version 1.99-21, but afaics the change to suppress kernel/initrd progress messages was made well before that version.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, the following steps can be taken to enable initrd and kernel boot messages. Please be aware that I'm doing this only on a server install with no graphical environment.  Desktop users may be unconcerned with a lack of boot nessages. So, take an unmodifed `/etc/default/grub` and make two changes:

1. Remove the 'quiet splash' options from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`
2. Uncomment `GRUB_TERMINAL=console`
3. As root or using sudo, run update-grub and reboot

If you want to take a further step and also obtain a console something like the old kernel option 'vga=xxx' would give, see the following url:
http://frontseed.com/entry/enable-frambeuffer-ubuntu-karmic-koala-using-grub2

Following the steps there, I only found it necessary (at least for ubuntu-12.04-1) to:

1. add 'vesafb' and 'fbcon' to /etc/initramfs-tools/modules and run

   > `# update-initramfs -u`
2. edit /etc/default/grub, adding only (for my desired screen resolution):
   `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX="1024x768"` then `update-grub` and reboot.

The solution isn't perfect, but is as close as I can get to a similar boot screen as with other distros that are still using grub-legacy.